# Spinner icon doesnt seem to work in <button> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flask

I am trying to recreate the buttons with spinners when clicked from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewDryga/GY6LC/

HTML

```
A and Button tags:
<p>
<a class="btn btn-success has-spinner">
   <span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-refresh"></i></span>
   Foo
 </a>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-success has-spinner" name="btn">
    <span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-refresh"></i></span>
    Foo
  </button>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.spinner {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s, max-width 0.45s; 
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s, max-width 0.45s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s, max-width 0.45s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s, max-width 0.45s; /* Duration fixed since we animate additional hidden     width */
}

.has-spinner.active {
cursor:progress;
}

.has-spinner.active .spinner {
opacity: 1;
max-width: 50px; /* More than it will ever come, notice that this affects on animation duration */
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
$('a, button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
});
```

I am able to recreate the  tag button to work but not the  tag. In his site (linked at top) they both work the same. Is there anything Im missing?

I am impletementing this in flask and using WTFforms, so i am getting the events through request.form.get['btn'], it appears that having the html inside the flask  tags is whats causing the issue

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry, i've narrowed down the issue to appear when i include the name for the button

Comment: Your code works for me as long as you include bootstrap and font awesome: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/qn7dLpfr/

Comment: I see the spinners too

Comment: Thinking about it, I have the Font Awesome font installed on my machine which is why I am able to see it in the fiddle. Are you actually loading the font files? on your page?

Comment: I see the spinner when I dont include the name="btn" for it. I think it might have something to do with flask?

Comment: this isn't a flask issue, it's a rendering issue. btn is a bootstrap class. using the same property value class AND name for btn is causing the problem, as you can tell. This type of setup might or might not work, which is why you're seeing other people having 'healthy' functionality. Avoid duplicate values like that unless it's strictly necessary. You need a name property- call it btn1 (name="btn1") for example.